# What is 'Inconsistent' & 'consistent' state?

Tags: state

I am confused of those terms. I am studying Read-Only Reentrancy, and just found that the attack happens when a function with 'view' is in inconsistent state. However, this is vague for me. Can I get an example of inconsistent and consistent state?

and why 'view' function is unguarded?